# Why Linux kernel memory subsystem is named slab

Tags: linux, kernel

Slab is of an object-caching kernel memory subsystem. But why call it slab?

I have a deep search. From Jeff Bonwick's paper, the name slab derives from one of the allocator's main data structures, the slab. So, why the data structure is called **slab**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [*slab*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slab), in common usage, refers to a big flat block of solid material. By analogy, a [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) manages large, contiguous chunks of memory, dividing them into smaller pieces for allocation.